# Java Custom exception throw behaves differently between different Projects

Tags: java

I am attempting to call the following in my code:

```
 public void checkParticleLightRestriction(Particle parent) throws LightException {
 if ( parent == null ) {
      throw new LightException("quantum-particle-restrict.23", this);
    }
```

In one Project the exception is thrown and the effect is similar to calling "return" whereby I am returned back to the point immediately succeeding where this method was called.

However in another Project I get thrown completed out of the current package and to a point way prior to the point preceeding this method.

It likes instead of being kicked out of a bar I am being deported all the way out of the country.

My option are the wrap the throw in a try / catch but I am wondering why this difference in behaviour beween the 2 projects ?

**09 May 2009**
I've been playing with your suggestions but I still haven't solved this. The call to throw the custom exception simply does not appear to be called in this particular project whether the Exception class extends RuntimeException or just Exception.

```
public class LightException extends Exception {

    ...etc

    public LightException(String errorCode, Object object) {

        super(errorCode == null ? null : errorStrings.getString(errorCode));
        this.errorCode = errorCode;
        this.invalidObject = object;
    }

    public LightException(String errorCode, Object object, Exception exception) {
        this(errorCode, object);
        add(exception);
    }

    ...
}
```

Any ideas appreciated.

Comment: Sounds like you've discovered Schrodinger's Exception. Oh, and it's 2010, not 2009 :)

Answer (score 2):

Without looking at the code that calls this method, it is impossible to tell what is going on.

Maybe in one project, the Exception is caught and not in the other project? That might happen if `LightException` is an unchecked exception.

EDIT:

You are saying (in your original question) that:

> the exception is thrown and ...
>   returned back to the point immediately
>   succeeding where this method was
>   called.

The only instance that this can happen is when the method that calls `checkParticleLightRestriction()` is wrapped in a `try...catch` block, such as:

```
try {
  checkParticleLightRestriction(particle);
} catch (LightException e) {
  // do something with e
}

// this is the point 'immediately succeeding where this method was called'
```

Comment: Wrapping it in a try catch at any point has no impact as I cannot get it to throw the exception within a try, catch at any point however it does throw in the other project.

Answer (score 0):

Exceptions are always caught by the first surrounding try/catch block that matches the type of the exception that is being thrown.  The try/catch block will match if it catches exception of the same type as the exception or one of the parent types.

Most likely your two project differ in what type of the exception they catch in the block that is calling the `checkParticleLightRestriction` method.

Answer (score 0):

> My option are the wrap the throw in a try / catch but I am wondering why this difference in behaviour beween the 2 projects ?

There is no difference in behavior. Whenever an exception is thrown, it will be caught at the 
"nearest" `catch` capable of catching it (near as defined by distance in stack trace). If you know what and where you want to catch something, say so and make it happen.

A `throw` is not a simple `return` statement.

#### See also

- [JLS 11.3 Handling of an Exception](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/third_edition/html/exceptions.html#11.3)

  > When an exception is thrown, control is transferred from the code that caused the exception to the nearest dynamically-enclosing `catch` clause of a `try` statement that handles the exception.

Answer (score 0):

Your `Exception` code looks fine.

The problem is most likely in the calling code.  It seems that the calling code in both projects are doing different things with the caught `LightException`.

> In one Project the exception is thrown and the effect is similar to calling "return" whereby I am returned back to the point immediately succeeding where this method was called.

here, the calling code could be swallowing the exception in a catch block and moving on.

> However in another Project I get thrown completed out of the current package and to a point way prior to the point preceeding this method.

in this case, the exception could be caught, potentially wrapped in a `RuntimeException`, and then rethrown from the catch block.  This would propagate the exception up the stack, to be then handled by code that handles exceptions generically.

Without knowing how this method is called, not much more can be added. If you have access to the code for those different projects, you can confirm the different handling techniques.

Answer (score 0):

I apologise to all who have racked their brains over this problem. I am at fault. It relates to a missing a resources further up the chain which due to a URL issue wasn't being found.

I will correct this and hopefully all will be solved.